# Button is not disabled at the initialization of page ,but gets disabled once you click it

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a very simple page , with an `input` field and a `button`.
I have to make `button` disabled when `input` field is empty . Once user clicks on it then input field will be cleared or reset .
My button is disabled once I click it. But its not disabled from the start.
My code is :

HMTL

```
<input type= 'text' [(ngModel)]="userName">

{{userName}}

<button[disabled]="userName==''(click)='resetUsername()'>RestUsername</button>
```

Typescript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector : 'app-server',
    templateUrl :'./server.component.html'               
})
export class Servercl {
   username=''

  resetUsername = function(){
       this.userName='';
   }         
}
```

Please tell where i am going wrong. Angular 4 is new to me.
I am making userName empty from the start . Dont understand what the problem is . Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable name's parts are all in the lowercase: `username`. But your attached variable to the `input` and `button` is with name `userName`. So

```
username !== userName
-----------------^--
```

Try to make them the same. Also you have some error in the `button` template.

```
<button[disabled]="username === ''" (click)='resetUsername()'>RestUsername</button>
```